# jQuery の XSS 脆弱性に対応する良い方法はないか ( v1.4.3 )

Tags: jquery, xss

はじめまして。

今度運用することになった Web サイトで、専門業者より XSS の脆弱性が指摘されました。

内容は・・・

> 最新版でないバージョンのjQueryが使用されています。
>   古いバージョンのjQueryでは、クロスサイトスクリプティング等の脆弱性が報告されているため、新しいバージョンのjQueryを使用することを推奨します。

とのことでした。

その Web サイトの jQuery のバージョンは v1.4.3 なので、確かに古いです。しかしながら、 jQuery というのは新しいバージョンにすると、今まで使っていたものが使えなくなっていたり、仕様が変わって Web サイトの画面の動作に影響するので、安易にバージョンアップするのはとても危険だと思います。

また、 jQuery というのは頻繁にバージョンアップされているので、バージョンアップするたびに最新版の jQuery に置き換えて XSS の対応しなければならないのは、とても現実的でないと感じています。

jQuery の XSS 対応について、何か良い方法はないものでしょうか？  
どうかお知恵をお貸しください。

Comment: jQueryのバージョンアップを嫌うのであれば、あなたが古いバージョンを保守するという意思決定をされたという意味だと思います。あとは旧版を使い続ける脆弱性と新版更改にともなうリスクのトレードオフで判断されるのが宜しいかと。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
他のWebサイトでも今回の質問をしているのですが、方向性が見えてきました。
これは肝を据えてバージョンアップに踏み切るしかなさそうです。

Answer (score 8):

> 最新版でないバージョンのjQueryが使用されています。
>   古いバージョンのjQueryでは、クロスサイトスクリプティング等の脆弱性が報告されている...

と言う指摘事項は、jQuery1.6.3未満のバージョンに存在する[CVE-2011-4969](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2011-4969)の脆弱性についての指摘です。アプリケーションコードに起因するXSSを指摘されているわけではありません。監査内容にもよりますがツールによる簡易診断程度であれば間違いなくアプリケーションコードは対象外で、アプリケーションコードに起因する脆弱性があるかないかは判断できません。以下の回答もアプリケーションコードに起因する脆弱性に対する対処は考慮していません。

一般原則は、

- セキュリティアップデートはできるだけ速やかに適用する。
- セキュリティアップデートでないものは、変更内容と開発の状況を考慮し適宜実施する。

です。セキュリティアップデートでないからといって古いバージョンで放置していると、もし脆弱性が発見されたときに、バージョンアップに伴う非互換の対応も慌てて実施しなければならないことになります。それを避けるため、ある程度は最新版に追随する必要があります。そういうことも考慮にいれての「適宜」です。

今脆弱性が発見されたらどのバージョンで対応されるのか、そのバージョンに更新するにはどの程度の確認や変更が必要になるのか、は把握しておく必要があります。

ただし、セキュリティアップデートがリリースされた場合の対応の例外として、その脆弱性の詳細について十分理解した上で、

- 自分の環境にはその攻撃経路が存在しないと明確に判断できる
- 信頼できるワークアラウンドを適用する
- アプリケーションコード側で対策を実施している/できる

場合については、アップデートをある程度先回しにするという判断をする場合もあります。この場合の判断は個々の環境次第ですので、環境を知らない人の意見やワークアラウンドの提案は聞くべきではありません。自分で判断ができないのであれば、原則に従い速やかにアップデートしてください。

> jQuery というのは新しいバージョンにすると、今まで使っていたものが使えなくなっていたり、仕様が変わって Web サイトの画面の動作に影響するので、安易にバージョンアップするのはとても危険だと思います。

この点については全くその通りです。バージョンアップの必要性を検討し、動作検証を行った上で実施されるのが当然のことです。

しかし、jQueryの1.4.3で脆弱性を指摘されているというのは、1.6.3未満で存在しているXSS脆弱性のことでしょう。これが公表されたのは2011年のことです。1.4.3のリリースは2010年です。4年前のプロダクトを使用していて3年以上以前の問題が放置されているというのは、「安易にアップデートするのは危険」だから許容されるレベルを遙かに超えています。

そして、jQueryではそれ以降、jQueryそのものについてセキュリティに関わるアップデートはされていないはずです。したがって、

> バージョンアップするたびに最新版の jQuery に置き換えて XSS の対応しなければならないのは、とても現実的でないと感じています

というのは的外れです。

---

以後余談。

jQuery以外は大丈夫なのか、というのが非常に心配です。HTML+Javascriptのみのwebサーバだとしても、OS自体に存在するここ最近のHeartBleedやShellShockなどの大物の脆弱性の対応は済んでいるのでしょうか。CMSなどの既製品のプロダクトが動いているのであればそちらの対応は大丈夫でしょうか。想像したくないですがもし既製品でない(自作や外部委託で作成された)Webアプリケーションが動いているようであれば、アプリケーションに特化した個別のセキュリティ監査は受けられていますか。

業務で運用されているWebサイトで、jQuery1.4.3の脆弱性が放置されていてどう対応すべきかわからない、というのはかなり深刻な状況です。受けられた監査がどのような物か分かりませんが、指摘事項がjQueryだけなのであれば、外部からソフトのバージョンや一部の設定をチェックする程度の簡易監査だと思われます。静的なHTML+JavascriptだけのWebサイト以上のことをやっているのであれば、システムについては詳細なセキュリティ監査を、運用についてもコンサルティングを受けられるべきだと強くおすすめします。(下手に事故が起きるとあなたの責任が問われますよ？)

Comment: 詳しい説明、どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

XSS脆弱性はjQueryのせいではありません。
使い方次第でどのバージョンのjQueryでも脆弱性のあるコードを書くことができます。

仮に何らかのjQueryプラグインで脆弱性が見つかって、プラグインをアップデートしようとした時に古いjQueryを使ってなんとか動かそうとする方がよほど現実的でないと思います。

それを踏まえて、まずは可能な範囲だけ部分的にjQueryをアップデートしてみてはどうでしょうか。
複数の異なるバージョンを同時に使い分けながら徐々にコード全体を新しいjQueryに移していきます。

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq_143 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-current.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq_current = $.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // 古いコードを無名関数でラップしてjq_143で$を上書きする
  (function ($) {
    // アップデートで問題になりそうなコードはjq_143を使う
    $(function () {
      ...
    });
  })(jq_143);

  // XSS脆弱性を抱えていそうな部分にjq_currentを使う
  (function ($) {
    $(function () {
      ...
    });
  })(jq_current):
</script>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、最新版のjQueryにしたところでXSS対策はOKってわけではないのですね。
コードの書き方に注意しないとXSSは引き起こすということが分かりました。

ただ・・・
どのようにコードを書けば「合格」となるのか分からないのが痛いです・・・
なんせ私、Web系を初めてまだ1週間。
今までは汎用機系とオープン系（クラサバのシステム）だけしかやってきませんでした。

周りのスタッフは全てWebデザイナーで、「JavaScriptとかjQueryとかPHPは全く分かりませ～ん」と言っていて、質問しても相手にしてくれなく本当に困っています。
そこで色々Webサイトを探してスタック・オーバーフローに辿り着きました。
すみません、愚痴になってしまいました。

Comment: Webアプリケーションの落とし穴と改善の勘所は色々なところで研究されています。まずはIPAの情報から確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。https://www.ipa.go.jp/files/000017316.pdf また、「体系的に学ぶWebアプリケーション」という本も非常に有益だと思います。

Comment: 情報提供、ありがとうございます。
確認ですが「体系的に学ぶ 安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方　脆弱性が生まれる原理と対策の実践」（徳丸浩 著）のことでしょうか？

Comment: 「徳丸本」と呼ばれています。合格ラインはシステムの要件に依存します、何もサービスしなければ鉄壁ですので。

Comment: なるほど！
「徳丸本」と呼ばれるほど有名なのですね！
すぐに購入して読んでみます。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「XSS脆弱性はjQueryのせいではありません」は誤りです。jQuery1.6.3以前にはjQuery自信の問題でXSSを引き起こす脆弱性があります(CVE-2011-4969)。指摘を受けているのはこれのことです。ですので、「可能な範囲だけ」「徐々に」などと言っている場合では無く、速やかにアップデートすべきです。さもなくば、一時的にはjQueryを無効にすることも選択肢です。

Comment: @suzukis いいえ。誤りではありません。jQueryはもとより`$()`に信頼できない文字列を入力した場合の安全性を保障していません。

Answer (score 1):

こちらにある回答も参考になると思います。

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13141045628